# what is practical application of non doership?

Tags: karma

If I am not doer, How should I spend my day?

Should i abandon personal goals as if I am not doer, how can I ensure action on those goals.

Also if I am just witnessing actions under compulsion of Gunas, and I am not the real doer, what should I do if something obviously wrong enters my thought. How do I ensure I don’t act on it

Comment: Why is it tagged advaita? Use correct tags.